# CentOS: Why am I seeing the same list of updates every time I login even though updates have been installed?

Tags: centos

**OS:** centos-release-8.2-2.2004.0.1.el8.x86_64

**Host:** Digital Ocean

Recently when I login to my account I get a long list of updates and activity.  I believe these updates have already been installed and when I attempt to install them I get this output.

```
$ sudo dnf update -y

Last metadata expiration check: 0:22:54 ago on Fri 14 Aug 2020 07:37:47 PM MST.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

However the next time I login I once again get the output below.  (I abbreviated this output considerably).

**Question)** Once these updates have been installed shouldn't they go away and not pop up the next time I login?  Is there a way to clear this out?  Do I not understand this properly?

```
The following updates were downloaded on 'server.example.com':

================================================================================

 Package                        ArchVersion                                    Repository Size  
                                                                                                                                                    
================================================================================

Installing:

 kernel                         x86_644.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2  
                                                                                                                                                                               BaseOS     2.8 M

 kernel-core                    x86_644.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2 
                                                                                                                                                                                  BaseOS     28 M

 kernel-devel                   x86_644.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2 
                                                                                                                                                                                  BaseOS     15 M

 kernel-modules                 x86_644.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2
                                                                                                                                                                                   BaseOS     23 M

Upgrading:

 annobin                        x86_648.90-1.el8.0.1 
                                                                                                                                                                                         AppStream  201 k

 boost-atomic                   x86_641.66.0-7.el8   
                                                                                                                                                                                         AppStream  13 k

 boost-chrono                   x86_641.66.0-7.el8  
                                                                                                                                                                                          AppStream  22 k

 boost-date-time                x86_641.66.0-7.el8 
                                                                                                                                                                                           AppStream  29 k

 boost-filesystem               x86_641.66.0-7.el8
                                                                                                                                                                                            AppStream  48 k

 boost-regex                    x86_641.66.0-7.el8  
                                                                                                                                                                                          AppStream  281 k

 boost-system                   x86_641.66.0-7.el8  
                                                                                                                                                                                          AppStream  18 k

 boost-thread                   x86_641.66.0-7.el8  
                                                                                                                                                                                          AppStream  58 k

 boost-timer                    x86_641.66.0-7.el8  
                                                                                                                                                                                          AppStream  20 k

 cloud-init                     noarch19.4-1.el8.7 
                                                                                                                   
Installing weak dependencies:

 PackageKit                     x86_641.1.12-4.el8   
                                                                                                                                                                                         AppStream  601 k

 elfutils-debuginfod-client     x86_640.178-7.el8  
                                                                                                                                                                                           AppStream  62 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install   13 Packages

Upgrade  295 Packages

Web console: https://server.example.com:9090/ or https://555.55.555.55:9090/
```

Comment: Can you please start a new terminal session, replicate the issue, and post the output as an edit to your question?